# Angular 2 (click) and (dblclick) on the same element not working good?

Tags: javascript, angular

When I do this:

```
<div (click)="func1()" (dblclick)="func2()">Some text</h1>
```

I actually get "func1()" to fire even on dblclick twice.

How can I make it work on the same element and work good?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be an Angular issue. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/bind-different-events-to-click-and-double-click/

The workaround is to not process the click event when a dblclick happens shortly afterwards.

Comment: Nice one Gunter. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-click-and-double-click-same-element) example using your technique.