# Component update only on double click for click event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular project, I created a search box with a button to get a search result from another component. I have a **router outlet** in my App Component and I switch **router outlet** with the **search result component** using the **search value** variable. I use a service to share this search value variable between components. So, when I click on a link in html, the **router outlet** will appear. When I click on the search input and do a search, **search result** will appear. My problem is, **when the router outlet is activated**, I have to **click twice on search button or hit twice enter key** to appear the search result.

Code -

**search.component.ts:**

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  value: string;

  constructor(private data: SendDataService){}

  show: boolean = true;

  showEl(){
    this.show = true;
  }

  newValue() {
    this.data.changeValue(this.value)
    this.show = false;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.data.currentValue.subscribe(value => this.value = value)
  }
}
```

**search.component.html:**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (click)="showEl()" (keyup.enter)="newValue()" (input)="showEl()">
<button (click)="newValue()">Search</button>
```

**search-result.component.ts:**

```
export class SearchResultComponent implements OnInit {

  _postsArray: = //JSON Object;
  value: string = "";
  filterarray: any[] = [];

  constructor(private data: SendDataService){}

  getData(){
    this.data.currentValue.subscribe(value => {this.value = value;
      this.showData();
    })
  }

  showData(){
    if (this.value != null){
      this.filterarray=
        this._postsArray.filter(f => 
          f.title.toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.value.toLowerCase()))
              .map(searchname=>searchname.title)
    }
  }

    ngOnInit(): void{
    this.getData();
  }

}
```

**app.component.html:**

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf="!value">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="value">
        <app-search-result></app-search-result>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I put **{{value}}** in app.component.html, it shows the value at the first click of search button. but **`<app-search-result>`** only appears in second click. How can I solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295288/angular-2-how-to-handle-single-click-and-double-click-on-the-same-html-dom

Comment: did you try using ng-change?

Comment: what is the similarity between click and ng-change?