# How to bind click (single) and double-click to same event (event binding) in Ionic v4, angular, typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular2-forms, ionic4

I am unable to bind event (in ionic-4) to double click. if i do double click to call the async call (method), the event got crashed and it wont listen to single click also afterwards. Is this the issue of Zone.js in angular?

code:

```
<ion-input  #inputdropdown 
  (click)="onFocus($event)" (dblclick)="onFocus($event)" >
</ion-input>
```

I want to trigger event using both single and double click.
please help.

Comment: check answers [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295288/how-to-handle-single-click-and-double-click-on-the-same-html-dom-element-usi?rq=1)

Comment: Also you missed a `"`. Possibly just a typo in your question

Comment: Yes i did :). i will correct it.