# Treat Single Click and Double Click as same

Tags: javascript, html, angular, onclick

I would like to be able to execute `foo()` once regardless of whether I click on the button once or twice.

```
<span> (click)="foo()" </span>
```

---

```
foo() {
    console.log("You've clicked on foo");
}
```

I've tried using this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48295484/9822083) but clicking on it twice still results in multiple console.logs. How would be able to only run this function once?

Note: Not really looking for triple/quadruple clicks (only single/double)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `setTimeout`, `clearTimeout` and handle user clicks:

```
<span 
    (click)="func1()" 
    (dblclick)="func2()">
    Hello
</span>
```

TypeScript:

```
timer = 0;
delay = 200;
prevent = false;

func1(){
    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
        if (!this.prevent) {
            this.sayHello();
        } 
        this.prevent = false;
    }, this.delay);
}

func2(){
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.prevent = true;
    this.sayHello();
}

sayHello(){
    console.log('Hello, world!:)');
}
```

[The work stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckim4t)

Comment: @Jedo Thank you very much! I am glad that it helped to you!:)